# How do hackers change their voice?

Tags: anonymity

How do hackers change their voice.

Comment: This is not a security question and it has nothing to do with "hackers". What can you "hack" with your voice? You do not provide context (what voice? in what context?) Or how this is a security question. Do you mean over the phone? In real life? In videos?

Comment: Guess what? Those voice modifications are easily bypassable, in addition to the fact that you can be identified by words and patterns extremely easily, regardless if your voice is modified or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criminals seeking to perpetrate fraud over the telephone have been known to use TTY services (which are intended to help deaf people communicate by phone) to disguise their voice.  See https://www.npr.org/2005/08/14/4799617/phone-service-for-deaf-a-target-for-abuse.

Comment: what about in a pre recorded video